# Как отделить модель и представление.(класс App не должен нести функции поддержки GUI) как это сделать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как отделить модель и представление.(класс `App` не должен нести функции поддержки GUI) как это сделать?

**код дизайна:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:/Desktop/un.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(299, 181)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 191, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 191, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 10, 81, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 130, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 100, 101, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить числа от 0 до 9"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Открыть \n"
" файл"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить"))
```

**код приложения:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
import design
import sys
import os

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_number)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.select_a_file)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.save)

    def select_a_file(self):

        self.input_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выбор файла', '')
        self.textEdit.setText(self.input_file)

    def add_number(self):

        self.c = 0
        number = 10
        pace = 100 / number
        with open(self.input_file) as f:
            self.text = f.read()
            for i in range(number):
                self.text += str(i)
                self.c += pace
                self.progressBar.setValue(round(self.c))

    def save(self):
        with open(self.input_file, 'w') as f_2:
            f_2.write(self.text)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Изначально был код с классом `App` и методом `add_number`

```
class App:

    def add_number(input_file):

        number = 10
        with open(input_file) as f:
            text = f.read()
            for i in range(number):
                text += str(i)

        with open(input_file, 'w') as f_2:
            f_2.write(text)

App.add_number('ok.txt')
```

GUI - представление которое нужно сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать? О какой модели и о каком представлении вы говорите? И что значит `класс App не должен нести функции поддержки GUI` ?

Comment: Изначально, был код только состоящий из класса App с одним методом add_number(добавляет в текстовый файл числа от 0 до 9). Я решил сделать из него приложение. Но я смешал модель и представление, а этого не надо делать.
Получается модель - это класс App с функцией add_number, a GUI- кнопочки, дизайн, то есть представление. Также есть вот такое пояснение: Для обратной связи с GUI использовать функцию обратного вызова.

Comment: + механизм сообщений windows (механизм событий)

Comment: Извини, не понял. Давайте с начала. Забудьте о своих понятиях модели, представлении и GUI и на простом человеческом языке напишите, примерно так: 1. Запустили приложение. 2.Нажимаем кнопку 'Добавить числа...' 3. ... . Т.е. опишите порядок действий и что должно происходить по каждому действию.

Comment: @LolPekPython, сделайте отдельный класс для поддержки логики вне GUI, раз не хотите бизнес логику в виджете держать :) Т.е. будет класс, у него будет какая-то логика, пусть `add_number`, вы этот класс создаете в `App` и вызываете нужные вам методы (`add_number`)

Comment: Я пока представить не могу как сделать отдельный класс для поддержки логики вне GUI, у меня нет опыта в этом

Comment: 1) Забудем что есть код приложения и код дизайна(реализация не должна быть такой в моем случае)

2) Изначально у нас есть только код с Классом App с одним методом добавления чисел от 0 до 9 в текстовый файл. (добавил в текст задания)

3)Нам нужно разработать представление (GUI) нашего приложения и связать с реализованной моделью(класс App), но связать их используя функцию обратного вызова (для вызова функции необходимо знать её адрес, если один объект хранит адрес метода другого объекта, он может этот метод активизировать. Этот механизм представлен механизмом событий.

Comment: (что то связанное с механизмом сообщений Windows)

Comment: @LolPekPython 1. Сделайте класс приложения, который ни от чего не наследуется 2. В отдельном классе (уже отнаследованном от `QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow`) реализуете графический интерфейс. 3. В классе приложения создаете объект класса из пункта 2. 4. ... 5. PROFIT!

Comment: Это будет соответствовать: "Для обратной связи с GUI использовать функцию обратного вызова."?

Comment: @LolPekPython, нет, это будет соответствовать разделению представления и остального кода. Дальше можно например в представление добавить методы типа `setOnOpenFile`, куда передаете метод, который должен вызываться при нажатии кнопки открытия файла. Этот метод и будет функцией обратного вызова.

Comment: @LolPekPython попробуйте почитать https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/  и посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042332/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-pyqt5  может чем-то поможет.

Comment: Мне нужно написать однопоточное приложение. За ссылки про многопоточность, спасибо)) в будущем освою

Comment: @LolPekPython  гляньте, попался пост как вызвать обратный вызов в главном потоке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181832/opening-new-window-while-out-of-focus-using-keyboard

Comment: Сложно, конечно, буду разбираться, спасибо за инфу))

Comment: @LolPekPython гляньте, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416422/showing-a-progress-bar-in-a-qmainwindow-from-a-callback-boto3-s3